# Is it possible to manage service dependencies through an API or Terraform?

Tags: pagerduty

Can the service dependencies on PagerDuty be managed through an API or Terraform? Does PagerDuty have a standard Terraform service provider for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, it does have a provider https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PagerDuty/pagerduty/latest/docs, as well as a resource for managing service dependencies https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PagerDuty/pagerduty/latest/docs/resources/service_dependency